# Ionic every time specific tab is selected event

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, events

Is there an event in Ionic that activates everytime i select this one specific tab?

Example:
My main tab is "Home"
If I switch to a different tab and the back to "Home" I want the event to fire
So basically everytime I go back to the tab "Home" I want the event to fire

So far I've tried looking at the angular life cycle, but I did not find an event that does what I would like.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the `ionTabsWillChange` event which will run each time a tab is activated. You can have your own stack and check if it is containing this tab.

```
<ion-tabs (ionTabsWillChange)="onTabsWillChange($event)">

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="tab1">
      <ion-icon name="flash"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab One</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab2">
      <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Two</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="tab3">
      <ion-icon name="send"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Tab Three</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

In your TS file:

```
onTabsWillChange(event) {
  const index = this.tabsStack.indexOf(event.tab);
  if( index > -1) {
    // Your logic here
    // Remove it from the array so it can pushed at the end again
    this.tabsStack.splice(index, 1);
  }
  this.tabsStack.push(event.tab);
}
```